# Dynamically Reassigning Filtered Text Box Extender

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a page with 8 Text fields, all these text boxes requires the same rules in regard to accepted characters/invalid characters.

My question is, should I have individual Filtered Text box Extenders for each Text Field or can I have a single Filtered Text Box Extender that I reassign the TargetControl.

Can you do this client side i.e. TextBoxX.onBlur() ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately you need to have 8 Extenders, though your idea is more elegant.